# How to create a new array, from another array at increments specified in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

Say if I have an array:

`a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])`

I want to create a new array which takes a and an increment, and creates a new array, for eg:
If I want increments of 2, then my new array would look like: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

or if I want increments of 3, then: [1, 4, 7, 10]

Is there any functions in numpy or python in general which allows me to do this? Instead of having to create a for loop which iterates through and creates a new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
a[::increment]
```

For example:

```
a[::2]
```

> array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])